# Google Play Developer Console Showing Incorrect Daily Installs

Tags: google-play, developer-console

Google Play Statistics show that my app received roughly 80 downloads in the past week. I know this incorrect because when I go to Admob, It says 18.4k impressions for that one app for the past 7 days.

And when I click 'Filter by Country' for that app, it shows multiple different countries with a decent amount of impressions.

What is going on. Why are the number of installs incorrect?